# How to use a repeat keyword in dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using actions-on-google and dialogflow to build a chatbot. The assistant asks the question and the user replies to it. Once the question has been asked and if the user says 'repeat' I want the question to be repeated. Is there any way I can do this?
Here is my code:

```
app.intent('First', (conv) => {

    const rating = conv.parameters.any;
    senddata[0] = qstion[0] + rating;
    conv.ask(qstion[1]);
});
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160588/how-to-repeat-last-response-of-bot-in-dialogflow

Comment: I used it, but how do I call the response?

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow has a concept of [session storage](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/save-data) which can store data only applicable to the session. In this way you can store data including your previous responses.

So it can be implemented as such:

```js
app.intent('First', conv => {
    const rating = conv.parameters.any
    senddata[0] = `${qstion[0]}${rating}`
    conv.data.lastResponse = qstion[1]
    conv.ask(qstion[1])
})

app.intent('Repeat', conv => {
    if (conv.data.lastResponse) {
        conv.ask(`Here is what I said before: ${conv.data.lastResponse}`)
    } else {
        conv.ask(`I didn't say anything. Can you ask me something else?`)
    }
})
```